# Broiler coming on during baking

Tags: baking, bread, cookies

When I am baking the broiler will come on and burn the top of my cookies or bread.  I am baking on the bottom and 3 rd from the bottom rack  what can I do to fix this?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what type of stove (electric or gas), as well as the brand or model. Even a picture of the control panel. It could be a setting--in which case someone might be able to help, or it could be working as designed--in which case someone might have advice using this type of oven.

Comment: The broiler should not come on during baking.  Do you have a manual or can you search online for product help from the manufacturer?

Answer (score 0):

If its electric, just put a rack up top and and put a sheet tray or cookie sheet on that so it blocks the direct heat from the broiler.